# Como puedo ocultar y mostrar contenido con 4 botones. cada boton con su respectivo contenido. en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cada botón con información diferente, cuando oprima 1 los otros 3 se oculten y al elegir otro se oculten los demás. dejo el código donde tengo 2 botones funcionando quise añadir otro botón y lo agrega pero no hace el funcionamiento de mostrar su respectivo contenido en el div. en pocas palabras el tercer boton no muestra su contenido. si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería :).Muchas gracias. soy nuevo en react.

```
class Ejemplo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { checked: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-6  mb-2">
          <div
            className="btn-group btn-group-sm"
            role="group"
            aria-label="Basic example"
          >
            {/* Este es el boton 1 */}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-nquote"
              className="button2"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(false)}
            >
              Todos mis cursos
            </button>

            {/* Este es el boton 2 */}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-flex"
              className="button1"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(true)}
            >
              Recursos
            </button>
            {/*Este es el boton 3*/}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-flex"
              className="button3"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(true)}
            >
              Tareas
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span>
          {this.state.checked ? (
            <div /* Este es el div 1 */ className="button1" >
              
<h4 className="title2">2 Descargas Nuevas</h4>
<hr></hr>
    <div className="tarea1">
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFile}  className="icon-document"></FontAwesomeIcon>

      
    <br></br>
<hr></hr>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div /* Este es el div 2 */ className="button2" >

                     <div class="seccion-course">            

                         <div className="curso1">
                          <img className="videos" src= {imagenes.video}/>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo podrías hacer es manejar un con otro tipo de variable el contenido oculto, en lugar de un booleano tal vez te sea mejor un string. Ya que el booleano solo te sirve para 2 botones (true para el botón 1 y false para el botón 2)

Sería algo así

```javascript
class Ejemplo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { checked: 'btn1' };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(checked) {
      this.setState({ checked });
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col-md-6  mb-2">
            <div
              className="btn-group btn-group-sm"
              role="group"
              aria-label="Basic example"
            >
              {/* Este es el boton 1 */}
              <button
                type="button"
                id="btn-nquote"
                className="button2"
                onClick={() => this.handleChange('btn1')}
              >
                Todos mis cursos
              </button>
  
              {/* Este es el boton 2 */}
              <button
                type="button"
                id="btn-flex"
                className="button1"
                onClick={() => this.handleChange('btn2')}
              >
                Recursos
              </button>
              {/*Este es el boton 3*/}
              <button
                type="button"
                id="btn-flex"
                className="button3"
                onClick={() => this.handleChange('btn3')}
              >
                Tareas
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span>
            {this.state.checked === 'btn1' && (
              <div /* Este es el div 1 */ className="button1" >
                
  <h4 className="title2">2 Descargas Nuevas</h4>
  <hr></hr>
      <div className="tarea1">
         <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFile}  className="icon-document"></FontAwesomeIcon>
  
        
      <br></br>
  <hr></hr>
              </div>
            ) 
            }

            { this.state.checked === 'btn1' &&
            (
              <div /* Este es el div 2 */ className="button2" >
  
                       <div class="seccion-course">            
  
                           <div className="curso1">
                            <img className="videos" src= {imagenes.video}/>
                          </div>
            </div>)
            }

            { this.state.checked === 'btn3' &&
            (
              <div /* Este es el div 3 */ className="button3" >
  
                       <div class="seccion-course">            
                                boton 3
                          </div>
            </div>)
            }
        </span>
</div>
        );

    }

    }
```